# Change X-Axis values in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, graph

I'm new to Microsoft Access, and I'm trying to make a line graph with the Insert Modern Chart option that shows the total monthly sales for each month from my given dataset: [image: Dataset] I want the months on the X-axis (Jan, Feb, March, etc.) and the total monthly sales on the Y-axis, giving me one line for all of the months

I've written an SQL statement to sum up all the values for the months, but when trying to make the chart, I can't get the X-axis working correctly, resulting in a graph that looks like this: [image: Graph].

Here's the SQL statement:

```
SELECT Sum(Sales.Jan) AS January, Sum(Sales.Feb) AS February, Sum(Sales.March) AS March, Sum(Sales.April) AS April, Sum(Sales.May) AS May, Sum(Sales.June) AS June
FROM Sales;
```

How can I set the X-axis to show the appropriate months instead of the values shown in the image? Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: Are you using Access Modern Chart? Edit question to show SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Modern Chart option.

Comment: First field is X-axis values, remaining fields are Y-axis data. Your query won't work with either chart utility. Is that really the way your data is structured in table?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, this was given as a college assignment. I had no issues making other charts, but this one is proving to be a pain.  I thought I was just missing something, but I guess it's harder than I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a UNION query to normalize data structure:

```
SELECT Sum(Jan) AS Data, "Jan" AS Mo, 1 AS MoN FROM Table1
UNION SELECT Sum(Feb), "Feb", 2 FROM Table1
...
UNION SELECT Sum(Dec), "Dec", 12 FROM Table1;
```

Use that query as source for chart RowSource:
`SELECT Mo, Data FROM Table1UNION ORDER BY MoN;`

I know this works with classic chart control and expect it will for Modern Chart as well.